# Angular JS Router and ng-repeat bound to $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am using angular router to create a SPA which retrieves data from an external database based on user preference and than displays data inside a table.
Here is what I have setup

Router:

```
App.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.php',
                controller  : 'mainCtrl'
            })
            .when('/territoryprint', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/print.php',
                controller  : 'mainCtrl'
            })
            .when('/territorymap', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/map.php',
                controller  : 'mainCtrl'
            });
    });
```

Next I populate an array via service that uses $http

```
fusiotablesService.getRecords($scope.tablenumber).then(
            function(success){
                for(var i=0;i<success.data.rows.length;i++){
                    var obj= {
                        f1: success.data.rows[i][0],
                        f2: success.data.rows[i][2],
                        f3: success.data.rows[i][3],
                        f4: success.data.rows[i][6]
                    };
                    $scope.Records.push(obj);
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            });       
   }
```

In pages/print.php I have setup the following:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr class="text-center">
        <th>Territory #</th>
        <th>Bell Code</th>
        <th>Full Address</th>
        <th>{{ Records.length }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-model="Records" ng-repeat="t in Records">
        <td>{{ t.f1}}</td>
        <td>{{ t.f2 }}</td>
        <td>{}</td>
        <td>{}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

However ng-repeat is not creating any `<td>` element and `Records.length` is 0.

Why is `ng-repeat` not being bound to `Records`?
Is my approach wrong? Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT**
Here is a console.log of $scope.Records
[image]

Here is the full controller

```
jwteApp.controller("mainCtrl",function($scope,$location,fusiotablesService,NgMap){
        /*====== INDEX ======*/    
       $scope.territoryRecords=[];
        $scope.territories=[];
        $scope.selectedterr=-1;
        $scope.selectedoption="SELECT OPTION";
        fusiotablesService.getTerritories().then(function(success){        
            for(var i=0;i<success.data.rows.length;i++){
                $scope.territories.push(success.data.rows[i][0]);
            }
            },function(error){
                console.log(error.data);
            });

       $scope.indexFormClick = function(){
           var path="";
           if($scope.selectedoption=="SELECT OPTION"){           
                alert("Please select an option");
           }
           else if($scope.selectedterr==-1){
               alert("Please select a territory");
           }
           else{
                switch($scope.selectedoption){
                    case "print" :
                    populateRecords();
                    path = "/territoryprint";
                    break;
                    case "map":
                    path = "/territorymap";
                    break;
                    default:
                    alert("Please select an option");
                }            
                $location.path(path);           
           }
       }

       /*====== TERRITORY PRINT ======*/
       function populateRecords(){
            fusiotablesService.getTerritoryRecords($scope.selectedterr).then(
                function(success){
                    for(var i=0;i<success.data.rows.length;i++){
                        var terRecObj = {
                            number : success.data.rows[i][0],
                            address : success.data.rows[i][2],
                            bellcode : success.data.rows[i][3],
                            notes : success.data.rows[i][6]
                        };
                        $scope.territoryRecords.push(terRecObj);
                    }
                    $scope.$apply();
                    console.log($scope.territoryRecords);
                },
                function(error){
                    console.log(error.data);
                }
            );       
       }

    });
```

Comment: It looks like your problem is not with ng-repeat, but more probably with the data structure or the the way you're trying to arrange it in Records. I suggest you debug your code by placing a brake-point to check the structure of the 'success' data and also when you push to Records. It is difficult for us to help you without a JsFiddle or so

Comment: I' ve added a picture showing that $scope.Records is succesfully populated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working example (without calling any remote api) - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3323/).

In your controller you're doing something like:

```
$scope.Records = []; // initialization
var obj = {
    f1: 'some territory',
    f2: 'some bell code',
    f3: 'some full address',
    f4: 'some number'
};
$scope.Records.push(obj);
```

And, if i'm right you missed the initialization of your `$scope.Records` array (see above).

Also, you don't need to call `$scope.$apply` right after calling the `push`.

---

**Edit:**

It looks like the reason is - you call your API and right after that you're calling `$location.path(path);`. It means that you routing will change the location **and you controller will be recreated**. Therefore, your array will be empty again (as before any API call).

Comment: I have initialized the array outside the function, otherwise I would get a "Records is undefined error"

Comment: I edited the answer. One question: how did you get the screenshot? Where did you put the breakpoint?

Comment: Ohh! That sounds right! How can I not recreate the controller each time?Is this a design issue?

Comment: The screenshot is taken when the populateRecords() function is called

Comment: You need to not calling `$location.path()`. Or you need to modify your routing to retrieve necessary data before controller initialization and inject this data inside the controller. [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) you can find the parameter `resolve` - that's what you need.